# Lato font is broken on Android 13 devices

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

In a react native project I'm using Lato font, it' working normal on iOS and older Android devices, only on Android 13 there's a line height issue, and some words are cut out.Does anyone know what has been changed that can cause such an issue?

When I change font the issue is not visible anymore.

NOTE: I've noticed this happens when I put text inside `View` or `Pressable` components.